# Задачка из Sololearn

Tags: python, комбинаторика

Всем привет!
Изучал язык Python по программе Sololearn. Были там интересные задачки.
Одна такая: От пользователя принимается слово (например, "мама") и программа должна вывести место позиция слова в ряду слов, образованных из этих букв, расположенных по возрастанию. Например, для указанного слова:
ААММ
АМАМ
АММА
МААМ
МАМА (слово пятое в ряду)
ММАА.
Я решил задачку таким кодом на основе математических знаний, вот таким кодом:

```
slovo = input()
slovo_poryadok = slovo
chislo_poryadok = slovo
chislo = slovo
chislo_zagotovka = slovo
slovarb = slovo
i = 0
chislo_poryadok = list(chislo_poryadok)
slovarb = list(slovarb)
for i in range(len(chislo_poryadok)):
    chislo_poryadok[i] = 0
slovo = list(slovo)
slovo_poryadok = list(slovo_poryadok)
slovo_poryadok.sort()
i = 0
j = 0
for i in range(len(slovo_poryadok)):
    if i == 0:
         chislo_poryadok[i] = 1
         slovarb[j] = slovo_poryadok[i]
    else:
         if slovo_poryadok[i-1] == slovo_poryadok[i]:
               chislo_poryadok[i] = chislo_poryadok[i-1]
         if slovo_poryadok[i-1] != slovo_poryadok[i]:
               chislo_poryadok[i] = int(chislo_poryadok[i-1])+1
               slovarb[j+1] = slovo_poryadok[i]
               j += 1
del slovarb[j+1:]
k = 1
kol_komb = 1
while k <= (i+1):
    kol_komb *= k
    k += 1
for k in range(len(slovarb)):
    n = 1
    while n <= slovo_poryadok.count(slovarb[k]):
        kol_komb /= n
        n += 1
kol_komb = int(kol_komb)
chislo = list(chislo)
chislo_zagotovka = list(chislo_zagotovka)
for n in range(len(chislo)):
    chislo[n] = slovarb.index(chislo[n]) + 1
    chislo_zagotovka[n] = chislo[n]
diapazon = kol_komb
otstup = 0
for i in range(len(chislo)):
    for j in range(len(slovarb)):
          if slovarb[j] < slovo[0]:
               otstup += diapazon*(slovo.count(slovarb[j]))/len(slovo)
          if j == len(slovarb)-1:
               diapazon = diapazon/(len(slovo)/(slovo.count(slovo[0])))
               del slovo[:1]
print(int(otstup)+int(diapazon))
```

Но я тупорылый))) Есть ли другие варианты решения?

Comment: Потестировал ваш код. Ошибка: `011111110` -> *8*, `100111111` -> *8*. Равенства (*8* и *8*) быть не может. Для второй комбинации правильный ответ - *9*.

Comment: Если в конце вместо приведений сделать округления, то ошибка уходит. Видимо дело в ошибках округления вещественных чисел. Это не дело, комбинаторика должна быть решена в целых числах.

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy как решение задачи код подошёл (вероятно, мне повезло, что попались определенные "слова" в тестировщике). Где именно округлить нужно? В самой нижней строчке?

Comment: Да, в самой нижней.

Comment: Понял, спасибо. Ты мой учитель)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Расчёт позиции через мультиномиальные коэффициенты.

Число различных перестановок символов в тексте равно [мультиномиальному коэффициенту](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%8D%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82). Факториал суммы делим на произведение факториалов. Введём для него обозначение:

*mс(k<sub>1</sub>, k<sub>2</sub>, ..., k<sub>m</sub>) = (Σk<sub>i</sub>)! / ∏k<sub>i</sub>!*.

Например, для слова *`CBCABBA`* *m = 3* (количество различных букв), *k<sub>1</sub> = 2* (число букв *`A`*), *k<sub>2</sub> = 3* (число букв *`B`*), *k<sub>3</sub> = 2* (число букв *`C`*).

Число перестановок *`CBCABBA`* равно *mc(2, 3, 2) = (2 + 3 + 2)! / (2!·3!·2!) = 210*.

Число перестановок для слова тоже обозначим как *mc(<слово>)*. Например *mc(`CBCABBA`) = 210*.

Составим упорядоченный список перестановок и определим какое место в нём занимает *`CBCABBA`*. Это место обозначим как *i(`CBCABBA`)*.

Все слова начинающиеся на *`A`* и на *`B`* в этом списке находятся до *`CBCABBA`*. На *`A`* начинается *mc(`CBCBBA`)* слов: из слова *`CBCABBA`* удалена одна любая буква *`A`*. Аналогично на букву *`B`* начинается *mc(`CCABBA`)* слов.

Число слов начинающихся на `C` равно *i(`BCABBA`)* - из исходного слова удалена первая буква. Задача сведена сама к себе, только букв стало меньше:

*i(`CBCABBA`) = mc(`CBCBBA`) + mc(`CCABBA`) + i(`BCABBA`)*

*i* получила реккурентное определение. База - ноль для пустой строки: *i() = 0*.

Сложность алгоритма пропорциональна *n<sup>2</sup>f*, где *n* - длина строки, *f* - коэффициент отвечающий за вычисление факториалов. *f* не превосходит размера ответа в цифрах (ну почти).

```
import collections
import math


def mc(word):
    """Мультиномиальный коэффициент для слова"""

    # превращаем слово в список "частот" символов
    ks = collections.Counter(word).values()

    # считаем мультиномиальный коэффициент
    return math.factorial(sum(ks)) // math.prod(map(math.factorial, ks))


def index(word):
    if word == '':
        return 0

    #      число слов у которых первая буква меньше word[0]
    #      ----
    return sum(
    #      удалить из слова любой один символ c
    #      ----------------------
        mc(word.replace(c, '', 1)) for c in set(word) if c < word[0]
    #                              ---------------------------------
    #                              для всех символов меньших первого
    ) + index(word[1:])
    #   ---------------
    #   число слов у которых первая буква равна word[0]


print(index(input()) + 1)
```

```
$ echo МАМА | python index.py
5

$ echo "А роза упала на лапу Азора" | python index.py
7514993507037377050
```

Comment: О, вы уже написали определение индекса в multiset permutations, и очень компактно.  (Не смотрится только `index` переменная в одноимённой функции)

Comment: Моя программа почему то дает другой ответ по Розе, скорее всего из-за неточности в записи очень больших чисел в памяти (мой косяк).  Я разобрал - это классный ответ, основанный как раз на знании комбинаторики. И это решение куда быстрее, чем моё. Моё почтение, надеюсь научиться программировать и математике, как вы

Comment: @НикитозСаныч У вас деление нецелочисленное (или питон второй?)

Comment: @MBo Похоже я что-то пропустил, деление целочисленное вроде как всё время получается... Питон третий. Для небольших значений букв (до 10) ошибок вроде не было

Comment: Так я тоже считал его же, только немного по другому. Идея моего кода в том, что наше "слово" перебирается по одному символу. По значению этого символа можно судить где в ряду будет расположение слово. Так я отсекаю те области множества, где его заведомо нет (проще говоря, если символов 6, а слово начинается с 1, то оно будет находится в области от 0 до 6!/6). И так, проходя все символы. Формула у меня та же получается.

Comment: @MBo, второй вариант исправляет ваше замечание.

Answer (score 1):

Вы решили задачу, определяя порядковый номер перестановки в лексикографическом наборе. На мой взгляд, это правильный путь- не генерировать кучу ненужного, если можно найти комбинаторикой.

Однако возможно, что преподы могут иметь в виду что-то попроще, с перебором этих самых перестановок.

```
print([''.join(t) for t in    
  more_itertools.distinct_permutations(sorted(list('MAMA')))].index('MAMA'))
```

Comment: Интересно  решить эту задачу без порождения списка.

Comment: Так конечно коротко, но слишком жадно, лучше внутри спискового включения проверять условие, а не через `index`. Для этого `enumerate` ещё добавить туда, чтобы индекс получить. Хотя это всё-равно лишний перебор, тут же `break` не сделаешь.

Comment: Спасибо, я позже разберу в Visual Studio этот код. Вообще Sololearn интересный ресурс, и там интересные задачки дают. Вот это одна из них.

Comment: По части решить задачу без порождения списка - вот я об этом то и думал. Я вначале пытался решить путем создания простой формулы из комбинаторики. При получении слова мы имеем величины: общее количество символов, количество вариантов символов, количество повторений каждого символа. По идее было бы круто решить в одну строчку формулой, подставив эти величины, но я так и не смог понять как, тем более, что тут играет роль и порядок символов

Comment: `sorted(list('MAMA'))` -> `sorted('MAMA')`

Comment: @CrazyElf, можно и с `break`: `word = tuple(word); print(next(i for i, w in enumerate(more_itertools.distinct_permutations(sorted(word))) if w == word))`.

Answer (score 1):

Я не знаю допустимо ли это в Sololearn, но тут явно напрашивается использование [библиотеки](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html), для получения всех возможных комбинаций из заданных символов

```
import itertools as it
word = "МАМА"
x = list(it.permutations(word))
x = list(set(x)) # Делаем эту процедуру, чтобы убрать из списка одинаковые наборы символов
x.sort()
for i in range(len(x)):
    if ''.join(x[i]) == word:
        print(i + 1, x[i])
```

Результат:

```
5 ('М', 'А', 'М', 'А')
```

Comment: Интересно решить эту задачу без порождения списка.

Comment: И `break` туда ещё. Нечего дальше перебирать, если уже нашли.

Comment: Мне писали про эту библиотеку на другом ресурсе. По существу - это почти то же, что я и написал (в т.ч. и по быстродействию), но "намного меньше буков". Соответственно, ответ конечно же верен. По части этой библиотеки - она вроде как стандартная, а значит ее можно использовать в Sololearn.